# Как избавиться от плавной прокрутки в VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Помогите избавиться от плавной прокрутки в VSCode (колесиком мыши). Если зажать `ctrl` и крутить колесико мыши то прокручивается как надо, как сделать по умолчанию?

В стандартный настройках не нашел решения, так же как и в Гугле, в чате все молчат.

Comment: [Smooth scroll in Visual Studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50954213)

Comment: Это "editor.smoothScrolling", не помогает, Вообще странно так как по описанию именно эта настройка должна отключать анимацию. Пробовал на разных устройствах так, что дело не в компе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос тем, что в ПО для мыши, поставил галку в контекстном меню иконки - "Microsoft Standard Wheel".

[image: Скрин]

Answer (score 0):

файл ... настройки ... параметры.

в поиске "editor.smoothScrolling"

параметр Editor: smooth scrolling -- снять галку.